# PHP Google Calendar Api add reminder to recurring events

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I started my project 1 year ago and never had to post in forums, 1 week ago i started developing with google calendar api and this is my 3rd post :s

I already create sucessfully single and recurring events, reminders for single events but now i need to know how to create reminders for recurring events with the Zend Gdata api.

This is the code i use to create reminders for single events:

```
function setReminder($client, $eventId, $minutes=15, $methods)
{
    $gc = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
    $reminder_types = array();
    if ($event = getEvent($client, $eventId)) {
        $times = $event->when;
        var_dump($event);
        foreach ($times as $when) 
        {
            if(in_array('alert',$methods))
            {
                var_dump('alert');
                $reminder_alert = $gc->newReminder();
                $reminder_alert->setMinutes($minutes);
                $reminder_alert->setMethod("alert");
                array_push($reminder_types,$reminder_alert);
            }
            if(in_array('email',$methods))
            {
                var_dump('email');
                $reminder_email = $gc->newReminder();
                $reminder_email->setMinutes($minutes);
                $reminder_email->setMethod("email");
                array_push($reminder_types,$reminder_email);
            }

            $when->reminders = $reminder_types;
        }
        $eventNew = $event->save();
        //var_dump($eventNew);
        return $eventNew;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is, for recurring events $event->when is empty.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after a lot of search and trial and error i found the solution to create recurring events with reminders.

Austin from Google wrote:

> At the moment, the Zend GData client library does not provide the
>   ability to directly add reminder when it is dealing with recurring
>   event.  This exceptional case is caused by the fact that there is no
>   gd:when element within a recurring event entry, and typically a
>   gd:reminder would exist inside a gd:when element.  The Zend client
>   library handle the general case and thus does not provide a way to add
>   reminder when there is no gd:when specified.

But there is an hack :) here it is how i did it:

```
function createRecurringEvent ($client, $calendar, $title, $desc, $where, $startDate, $startTime, $endDate, $endTime, $repeat, $endRepeatDate, $endRepeatTime, $tzOffset, $minutes=15, $methods)
{
    $frequence = "";
    $recurData = null;
    $gc = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
    $newEntry = $gc->newEventEntry();
    $newEntry->title = $gc->newTitle(trim($title));
    $newEntry->where = array($gc->newWhere($where));

    $newEntry->content = $gc->newContent($desc);
    $newEntry->content->type = 'text';


    switch ($repeat) {
        case "d":
            $frequence = "DAILY";
            break;
        case "w":
            $frequence = "WEEKLY";
            break;
        case "m":
            $frequence = "MONTHLY";
            break;
        case "y":
            $frequence = "YEARLY";
            break;
    }

    $startDateTime = getIcalDate($startDate . " " . $startTime);
    $endDateTime = getIcalDate($endDate . " " . $endTime);
    $endRepeatDateTime = getIcalDate($endRepeatDate . " " . $endRepeatTime);

    if ($recurData == null) 
    {
        $recurData =
            "DTSTART:{$startDateTime}\r\n" .
            "DTEND:{$endDateTime}\r\n" .
            "RRULE:FREQ={$frequence};UNTIL={$endRepeatDateTime}\r\n";

    }

    $newEntry->recurrence = $gc->newRecurrence($recurData);

    $event_xml = simplexml_load_string($newEntry->saveXML());

    if(in_array('alert',$methods))
        $event_xml->addChild('gd:reminder  xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" minutes="15" method="alert"');
    if(in_array('email',$methods))
        $event_xml->addChild('gd:reminder  xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" minutes="15" method="email"');
    $xml = str_replace("atom:reminder","gd:reminder",$event_xml->asXML());

    $gc->post($xml, $calendar);
}
```

The 100 parameters will be replaced by an object this is only for test.
I hope this helps someone else since this api is a nightmare.
I'm thinking in creating a tutorial about this in the future.